# Hiding Wordpress parent theme

Tags: wordpress

I am using the child theme and have renamed it to the new theme name. However, the parent theme is still viewable in the admin area with the original theme name. How do I hide the parent theme? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is probably better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this cannot be done. The idea behind child themes is to be Update Safe.

This means, you can update the parent theme and all the child theme functionality goes unaffected. If you want to hide the parent theme, you are better off forking it.

Answer (score 0):

As i seen on `wp-admin/themes.php` file that wordpress use function called `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` to collect the available theme information and then display it on themes page.

The function `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` located on `wp-admin/theme.php` may be line `409` and seems the function have filter `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js`, so i think this will be done with this filter by unset the selected theme (parent theme to hide) before displayed to the available themes.

try add filter like this to your `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'wp_prepare_themes_for_js', 'test_hide_themes', 11, 1 );
function test_hide_themes($prepared_themes){

    // hide parent-theme theme
    unset($prepared_themes['your-parent-theme-slug']);

    return $prepared_themes;
}
```